# How to fit the content of the site in any resolution CSS

Tags: css, css-tables

I have my login.css here:

```
#contentContainer{

margin-top: 10%;

}
```

and here's the piece of my PHP file:

```
  <div align="center" id="contentContainer">
        <div id="Login_Cont"></div>
        <div class="login_logo"></div>

  </div>
```

I put the content of my site in a one big div, I called it contentContainer. Now, How can I fit the content of my site in any resolution, I've tried already the media screen tricks/css tricks but it doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "fit the content of my site"? Could you give an example?

Comment: Question is not specific enough.

Comment: any jsfiddle ? not getting your question

Comment: @Zhihao, The site have a maincontainer which is the background of the website, Now I need to put the login interface inside of the maincontainer so I made the contentcontainer but if whenever I resize the browser, the content goes anywhere, instead of staying at the center.

Comment: So you want to absolute center (vertically and horizontally) the contentContainer whatever the size of the window?

Comment: Than check AndySX's answer. I wanted to post basically the same answer.

Comment: Guys, Please stop down voting me, sorry if it made you inconvenient with my question. Please understand, begging you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would like the contentContainer to float in the middle of the screen?

Is it something like this you're after:

```
#contentContainer {
background-color: #ccc;
height: 300px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -150px;
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: @AndySix, yes I need to float the content at the middle of the screen in any resolution. I'll try your code. Thank you.

Comment: It's sad but that's the only crossbrowser way to absolute centering, as far as I know. I think absolute centering is a common task, there should be an easier/nicer/prettier/shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

You can give that container width in percentage like

```
#contentContainer{
   width:100%;//likewise
   margin:auto;//to center your div
}
```

or best use media queries

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 320px)
{

}//likewise define for each screen resolution
```